# How to create socket to receive both text and image

Tags: java, sockets, arrays, utf

I want to create a server which receives both text and image. For text I used `DataInputStream dis.readUTF()`, and for image, I used `ObjectInputStream ois.readObject()` to read the image as `byte[]`. So how can I write code to detect the data receiving is text or `byte[]`?

Comment: Why don't you do like [HTTP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)? first meta-data then data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use some kind of signal from the client to know whether it is sending text or an image.

Alternatively, you could receive on different ports depending on the type of input.